# use of outer joins in where clause if the value is defaulted

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, where-clause, outer-join

In the where clause used `column_name(+)=some value`, what is the use of **right outer join** this column

```
Ex: deptno(+)=30
```

please explain

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Ex: deptno(+)=30

Without any other table join it is meaningless.

The Join against a **Constant** involves a join event in which a constant is being compared to one of the columns. The error is that the **OUTER-JOIN** must also include the OUTER-JOIN construct in the constant test. Without it, the join can fail to complete a row. This is the most pervasive miscoding of OUTER-JOIN because the behavior of a constant test when considered as part of a join event of an OUTER-JOIN is different from its behavior when it stands alone. I have included a sample of this behavior difference with two seemingly semantically equivalent queries that are not equivalent because one uses a true join and one does not. The point being that OUTER-JOIN constructs only give meaning when they are actually being used in a join. The solution is as we have seen, to code the missing OUTER-JOIN constructs.

See [Common errors seen when using OUTER-JOIN](http://www.orafaq.com/node/855)

Your query is valid for something like this:

```
select <column_list>
from   T1, 
       T2
where  T1.C1 = T2.C1(+)
and    T1.C2(+) = ‘Y’;
```